# Using library that use Spring internally

Tags: java, spring, maven, jakarta-ee

I am creating a new application using Spring. While working on that I saw the need for separating some of the code to a new Maven project. I want to use Spring in this project too. So I will get a dependency on this project.

I have not done that before so my question is if it is something that I need to know? Will the  XML-configuration file from the two projects crash with each other? Basically, is it something special with creating libraries with Spring and then using them in another Spring based application?

Comment: If you're writing a Spring-based library and using XML configuration (though JavaConfig is increasingly becoming the standard), just give your XML file a name that won't collide, like `/META-INF/spring/my-library.xml`, and import that from your final deployment package.

Comment: Ah, of cource. Are there other things to remember when creating Spring -based libraries? Or is it straight forward code as normal?

Comment: @chrylis How do you bootstrap a library module that use Spring? I mean, how do you initially read the configuration?

Comment: You just make sure the configuration file is available on the classpath as usual, and the project you actually runs needs an `import` statement.